# Populate php dropdown box from postgresql database

Tags: php, forms, postgresql, drop-down-menu

I need to populate a dropdown list of book titles from my postgreSQL database using a query such as SELECT title FROM books WHERE ownedBy = [users facebook ID] and then use the selection by the user to display the rest of the information on that book. The page is a facebook app, which is how I'm getting the facebook ID.

This is the relavent section of code so far, mostly created from various answers to similar questions I have found.

```
<form action="updateform.php" method="post">
<select name="booktitle" id="booktitle">
<option>Select book</option>
<?php
$db = pg_connect("host=ec2-54-243-190-226.compute-1.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=d6fh4g6l0l6gvb    user=zmqygfamcyvhsb password=1Apld4ivMXSK8JZ_8yL7FwIuuz sslmode=require options='--client_encoding=UTF8'") or   die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
$sql = pg_query("SELECT title FROM books WHERE ownedby='$user_id'";
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['title']).'"></option>';}
pg_close($db);
?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user_id); ?>">
//other form elements here
</form>
```

**UPDATED: I hadn't closed the hidden field, so that seemed to fix the error where it wasn't showing up. The dropdown list is not populating, but I am not getting any errors in the server log.**

If anyone can help me get the drop down box part to work, that would be great for now, I'll work on figuring the rest out myself once this part is working.

Comment: is the SQL certainly returning rows with the passed back user_id?

Comment: @DaleBetts When I run `SELECT title FROM books WHERE ownedby = [my facebook id];` directly on the database it does return values, but I don't know how to test if the PHP is successfully retrieving them. EDIT: It is currently displaying the correct number of lines on the dropdown box, but without text)

Answer (score 2):

You should write

```
$sql = pg_query($db, "SELECT title FROM books WHERE ownedby='$user_id'");
```

Also, the displayed name in your options has to be specified.

```
echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['title']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['title']).'</option>';
```

Comment: That seemed to stop the errors. Now the dropdown box is just giving me 2 blank options.

Comment: @TheMarron See update. You have to specify the display text of your options.

Answer (score 0):

in your query '$user_id' is null. first check the value of '$user_id' carefully. then it will work.

Comment: $user_id is assigned a value earlier on in the code `$user_id = $facebook->getUser();`

Comment: if $user_id is already assinged then value of this not get in query. or try after close the brackets of '$sql' and hidden button is not correctly close. so first do it and then try. hope this will help u.